# Backup MySQL Database At Specific Location With Specific Name Which Includes Timestamp

Tags: mysql

Currently i can backup my database at specific location using following command, but i want to add `timestamp` in the filename before (`.sql`) extension.

Currently working code:

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -p123 -R -E qc > "C:\Users\Server\Documents\qc.sql"
```

I was trying something like this:

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -p123 -R -E qc > "C:\Users\Server\Documents\qc_$(date +%Y%m%d).sql"
```

But above code has errors showing:

> mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "+%b-%d-%Y-%H-%M-%S).sql"

I am also looking for auto delete functionality for previously backuped script files.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your Linux code won't work on your Windows machine ;)

Comment: Okay i am sorry, Can U please suggest windows alternative for this

Answer (score 0):

```
dd = %DATE:~0,2%
mm = %DATE:~3,2%
yyyy = %DATE:~6,4%
hh = %TIME:~0,2%
```

Working command: (output: 'qc_'yyyy-mm-dd_hh'h')

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -p123 -R -E qc > "C:\Users\Server\Documents\qc_%DATE:~6,4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%_%TIME:~0,2%h.sql"
```

Hope this helps